# very high memory consumption from ocaml multicore

Tags: ocaml, multicore

For testing OCaml multicore, I installed opam version 4.12.0+domains+effects and implemented quicksort using tasks.

To my surprise, even the purely sequential version has very high memory consumption if run from within a thread pool (Domainslib) context: I see ocaml using 800 megabytes of RAM to sort an integer array of size 1 million if run within the following context:

```
let pool = Tsk.setup_pool ~num_additional_domains:3 () in
let run f = Tsk.run pool f in
```

The problem does not occur without this pool context.

Another surprising aspect: 256 gigabytes of virtual memory allocated for running anything inside ocaml.

If I run the computation over 4 threads, it dies before the end (but somehow the process returns 0).

Have I installed an incorrect version of ocaml multicore? What should I pick? (what opam command line ;) )

Comment: I don't think SO is the appropriate place to ask this question, both because it's likely to lead to discussion and because answers will become obsolete almost immediately since it's still in development. I would suggest you ask on https://discuss.ocaml.org/ instead, or just read the [latest monthly Multicore update](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/multicore-ocaml-march-2022/9692/2).